# Is it possible to pass the same data as props to a parent component?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

So my partner designed the frontend to our website and I found a way to pass data from one child component to a parent component and then pass it to a different child component but now I am stuck on how to progress.

What I currently have is this:

```
const [dataFromCardSearch, setDataFromCardSearch] = React.useState([]);

const handleDataFromCardSearch = (data) => {
    setDataFromCardSearch(data);
  };

<CardSearch sendDataToDeckEditor={handleDataFromCardSearch} />
        <DeckList clickedCard={dataFromCardSearch} />


export default DeckEditor;
```

The `<CardSearch/>` component is a search function that pulls cards from the database based on the search query. In this component I have made these cards have an `onClick` function that passes the clicked card's data to the `<DeckList/>` component.

In the `<DeckList/>` component the main part is that it has 2 radio buttons that corresponds to 2 different lists, "main" and "side" and whichever radio button is clicked, the card should be added to that list.

Here's a picture that hopefully shows more clearly what I'm trying to do:

[image: Frontend of website]

However because its a Deck list, it is common for there to be more than 1 copy of a card within a Deck list. However at the moment only 1 copy of the card is added to the `<DeckList>` component.

I think the reason this is happening is because the `dataFromCardSearch` state stays the same because I am clicking on the same card. FYI this behavior doesn't change even if I click on a different card and then clicking on the original card.